# PHP image verification code is not displayed

Tags: php

Here is checks.php given by my teacher:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("content-type:image/png");
$image_width=70;
$image_height=18;
srand(microtime()*100000);
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
   $new_number.=dechex(rand(0,15));
}
$_SESSION[check_checks]=$new_number;

$num_image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);
imagecolorallocate($num_image,255,255,255);
for($i=0;$i<strlen($_SESSION[check_checks]);$i++){
   $font=mt_rand(3,5);
   $x=mt_rand(1,8)+$image_width*$i/4;
   $y=mt_rand(1,$image_height/4);
   $color=imagecolorallocate($num_image,mt_rand(0,100),mt_rand(0,150),mt_rand(0,200));
   imagestring($num_image,$font,$x,$y,$_SESSION[check_checks][$i],$color);
}
imagepng($num_image);
imagedestroy($num_image);
?>
```

And I use it by a img tag `<img src="checks.php">`, but the image doesn't display and no errors show. I remember I have tested it successfully on my experimental class. So I guess if I ignored something. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you have GD library installed and enabled on this PHP installation?

Comment: why image src have a php file ?<img src="checks.php">

Comment: @AhmedGinani that's fine that serves this purpose

Comment: Also please improve upon your teacher's code and write `$_SESSION['check_checks']`

Comment: @HankyPanky I have browsed the PHPINFO page, and find GD library enable. And I can't clearly understand what writing `$_SESSION['check_checks']` means.

Comment: @dapao He means you should add the '' in front and after check_checks. Your teacher wrote `$_SESSION[check_checks]`